# How to Filter a Map to retain only specific keys in Java

Tags: java

I have been using `map.keySet().retainAll(<set of keys>)` for this purpose , but just came across a scenario where this is not working as expected.

See the sample code below. I am expecting `object1` map to be returned with keys (key1 and key2) after filter, but this gives me blank output. Note: if I uncomment the line that adds key3 to `object1` , it is working fine (returning map with key1 and key2). Why? How to fix this issue? Is there any alternative approach?

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Map<String,Object> object1 = new HashMap<>();
        object1.put("key1","One");
        object1.put("key2","Two");
        //object1.put("key3","Three");

        List<Map<String,Object>> objects = new ArrayList<>();
        objects.add(object1);


        Set<String> attributes = new HashSet<>();
           attributes.add("key1");
           attributes.add("key2");

        System.out.println("Objects before filter:"+objects);

        System.out.println("Objects after filter:"+objects.stream().filter(map -> map.keySet().retainAll(attributes)).collect(Collectors.toList()));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because the filter `map.keySet().retainAll(attributes)`  returns `false` as the set was not changed:

[`Set#retainAll()`'s javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)):

> @return true if this set changed as a result of the call

Are you looking for [`Set#containsAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)) instead?

> Returns true if this set contains all of the elements of the specified collection.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. containsAll itself will not help solving my usecase as i needed to retain the keys in the map that exists in other collection in all cases like (set contains key that might match exactly with map , may contain extra keys , may contain less keys..etc). However javadoc that you pointed helped me out to figure out one solution , so far it seems to be working for all scenario's. 
                                                                     objects.stream().filter(map -> (map.keySet().retainAll(attributes) == false ? true:true)).collect(Collectors.toList()));

Comment: @my2cents `map.keySet().retainAll(attributes) == false ? true:true` makes absolutely no sense. I think you might be looking for `Stream.peek()`.

Comment: @shmosel why do you think so? do you think it does nothing? i am doing retainAll on this and incase of false scenario's returing the full map instead of nothing. see the difference in this System.out.println(objects.stream().filter(map -> true).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        System.out.println(objects.stream().filter(map -> false).collect(Collectors.toList()));

Comment: Why are you filtering altogether? Are there maps you want to exclude from the result?

Comment: yes , if none of the keys matches , then exclude the full map , if few key's in that map matches , then retain only those keys of that map from the list of maps

Comment: But your filter never returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't actually care if the map was retained or not, try calling it like this:

```
System.out.println("Objects after 
filter:"+objects.stream().filter(map -> 
{ 
  map.keySet().retainAll(attributes); // Modify your map
  return !map.keySet().isEmpty(); // Include sets with data
}
).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: i accepted your answer too , since i am new and have no points , it seems not reflected here